# How to add gradle task to compile additional SourceSet

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin, dsl, source-sets

I have a KotlinJS-project using

```
plugins {
  kotlin("js")
}
```

Kotlin-compiler-plugin that generates new .kt-files (right now in folder `$buildDir/src/main/generated`) when task build is executed.
Unfortunately I have to call build a second time to compile the generated sources
Therefore I would like to add a task that compiles the generated sources by

```
tasks.register("compileGenerated", org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.Kotlin2JsCompile::class) {
    sourceSets {
        create("generated") {
            kotlin.srcDir("${buildDir}/src/generated/kotlin/")
            dependsOn(sourceSets.getByName("main"))
        }
     }
}
```

That task I would call at the end of each build using `finalizedBy`

Trying it I just get the following message:

```
> Could not create task ':examples:nestedmodel:model:compileGenerated'.
> Project#afterEvaluate(Action) on project ':example' cannot be executed in the current context.
```

To be honest I have no idea, why...

Comment: Can please post the whole build file ?

Comment: You can have a look at it at https://github.com/jwstegemann/fritz2/tree/master/examples/nestedmodel/model